# Can a prone ally be used to flank an enemy?

Tags: dnd-4e, prone

If a prone ally is on the opposite side of a creature than another standing ally, does the prone ally allow the standing ally to gain combat advantage?

Can the prone ally also gain combat advantage from flanking an enemy with a standing ally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

Flanking requires that the other person meet the following conditions:

- Opposite sides (prone characters still occupy the same space as they would if they were standing).
- Must be Able to Attack (prone characters can still attack).

Answer (score -4):

As a DM I do NOT give my 3.5e players the prone flanking advantage unless they have something to help with the situation.  Prone is very situational on how the DM describes it.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I wanted to point out that this question was tagged for D&D4, aiming your answer for a different version is liable to lead to downvotes.

Comment: Thats ok I pointed out it was for 3.5e but DM can use them for 4.0 at their choice.

Comment: Alright then, I did have to follow through with the downvote.

Comment: I'd imagine that "something to help with the situation" includes being armed and capable of a melee attack?  Prone in 4th edition does not remove either of those two effects.